# QT Configure - QFSFileEngine::currentDirectory cannot stat(".")

Tags: linux, qt, x86, 64-bit, inode

I found an interesting problem while setting up a new system and the resolution was rather easy, but it is a hard one to track down.  We have a rather large application that uses QT.  It is over 20 years old, and although it has been maintained and upgraded with new features over the years, it is still strictly 32 bit.  The easiest way to get it to compile and everything to work is not to pass -m32 to gcc but to actually compile a 32 bit version of gcc and use that.  So I did and when the makefile hit QT to configure it, I get the following error message;

> QT Configure - QFSFileEngine::currentDirectory cannot stat(".")

Has anyone seen this error message before, and explain how to solve it?

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to Stack Overflow. We appreciate (and welcome!) you sharing your own question and answers on Stack Overflow, but please post your "solution" as an actual answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I've edited the solution out of your question, and made the question itself more "question-y". You can get the text you wrote for your solution (and copy/ paste it into an answer) from http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36609480/revisions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the filesystem I was using was rather large (5 TB) and the inode numbers were > 4 billion.  To get around this, I had to export CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to be -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64.